# Как залить область внутри path в SVG?

Tags: css, svg

Здравствуйте, начал изучать SVG!

Такой вопрос, вот, например, прямоугольник (rectangle) или круг (circle) средствами svg закрасить легко, просто свойство одно!

А если у меня фигура неправильная, ну, например, котенок нарисован с помощью path, возможно ли как-то выбрать область, которая ограничивается этим path, и закрасить ее?

Для того чтобы поменять цвет этого котенка при наведении мышы, например?

Заранее благодарен за ответ!

Comment: @pankovalxndr, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 3):

Можно, используя атрибут `fill-rule`. Посмотрите материал, например, у [yoksel](http://css.yoksel.ru/svg-fill-and-stroke/). Там найдете раздел про `fill-rule` с примерами.

Answer (score 1):

Можно в стилях прописать:

```
path {
   fill: #000
}
```

Или поставить атрибутом:

```
<svg><path fill="#000"></path></svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

Заливка фона любых объектов `svg` делается свойством `fill`:

```html
<svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 400 400"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

  <path d="M 100 100 L 300 100 L 200 300 z"
        fill="orange" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

Наверняка ваш котенок - это не один path, так что если вы хотите заливать всего котенка при наведении мыши - добавьте к каждому path класс, а затем с помощью псевдокласса `:hover` задаете правило `fill`
Например:

```
.cat:hover {
fill: #fff;
}
```